# collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld' when using using CC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Been smashing my head against this one for a few days.

I have wsl2 running with ubuntu 20.04 trying to use gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major to compile and link my files.

When it starts to link the .o files i get the following error:
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'

When i myself use ld its located in /usr/bin/ld. This is added to path and i have also set the permissions.

running verbose on the output i see that the input is:

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-gdwarf-2' '-mthumb' '-mabi=aapcs' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-fno-strict-aliasing' '-mcpu=cortex-m0' '-specs=nano.specs' '-Llink' '-T' 'application.ld' '-o'
```

ld is set at such:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Oct 20  2021 /usr/bin/ld -> x86_64-linux-gnu-ld

Tried setting PATH variables.
Chmod on ld.

Comment: that's a symbolic link, not the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I had used unar to extract gcc, it didnt extract the files correctly. using tar -xvf  helped